# 'NoneType' object is not callable when I learn web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm a new web scraping coder.

**My code is this:**

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html=urlopen("http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/warandpeace.html")
bsObj=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
namelist=bsObj.findall("span",{"class":"green"})
for name in namelist:
    print(name.get_text())
```

**And the console is this:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "F:\Eclipseworkspace\PythonLearn1_12\src\Test1\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    namelist=bsObj.findall("span",{"class":"green"}) TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: It is spelled [`find_all`, with an underscore](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree), not `findall`.

Comment: If you add `print bsObj` after line 4, what does it return?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: or `findAll` with an uppercase?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: yes, but that's there only for backwards compatibility with BeautifulSoup 3. The recommended spelling is `find_all`.

Comment: @schaiba: `bsObj` is not `None`, if that's what you are thinking. What happens is that *arbitrary attributes* are treated as `soup.find(attribute_name)` searches, and there is no `<findall>` tag in the document so `None` is returned.

Comment: @schaiba: If `bsObj` was `None`, you'd get an attribute error, not a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply made a typo, `findAll` is with a uppercase `A` or you can use `find_all` (with underscore) which is actually the method one should use in `bs4`.

The reason you get this error is because a `BeautifulSoup` object will treat generic attributes (attributes not part of the `dir(..)` as `find`-requests). If the query is not found, it returns `None` for every queried attribute that is not specified.

```
>>> repr(bsObj.findall)
'None'
```

so now you call (`bsObj.findall(..)`) on a `None` object and that will not work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually I just realize my fault after sending the question. I'm sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
namelist=bsObj.find_all("span",{"class":"green"})
```

Old Version: `findAll`

New Version: `find_all`

Wrong Version: `findall`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry, It's really a stupid problem.